# Cannot implicitly convert type... with property

Tags: c#, properties, type-conversion, implicit

I've been trying to set up a triangle class that contains three Vector3's and an integer.

Here's the class constructor:  (not sure that's the right term, I'm an amateur)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;

namespace Icosahedron_Test
{
    class TriXYZ
    {
        Vector3 vertex1;
        Vector3 vertex2;
        Vector3 vertex3;
        int depth;
        float material1; // float for first material value amount (in %)  deals with blending
        float material2; // float for second material value amount (in %)  deals with blending

        Vector3 vValue;  // place holder for vertex properties "set"
        int dValue;  // place holder for depth properties "set"

    public TriXYZ(Vector3 pos1, Vector3 pos2, Vector3 pos3, int tDepth)
    {
        vertex1 = pos1;
        vertex2 = pos2;
        vertex3 = pos3;
        depth = tDepth;
    }
```

This is how I'm setting up the property:

```
public Vector3 GetVertex1
{
    get { return vertex1; }
    set { vertex1 = vValue; }
}
```

And this is how I'm calling the property from another class:

```
Vector3 cVertex1;
TriXYZ cTriangle = triangleList[listPos];   // triangleList is a TriXYZ[] array
.
.
.

cVertex1 = cTriangle.GetVertex1;
```

The error I am getting is:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Vector3' to 'Icosahedron_Test.TriXYZ'
```

I understand what this error usually means, essentially that I am trying to assign a string to an integer or something like that.  What I don't understand is why I am seeing the error here.  the variable cVertex1 is a Vector3 variable, and the return value of vertex1 is also a Vector3 variable.

Can anyone see why I am running into this problem?

Here's teh full code for the TriXyZ class and the Icosahdron class that I've developed so far:

TriXYZ:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;

namespace Icosahedron_Test
{
class TriXYZ
{
    Vector3 vertex1;
    Vector3 vertex2;
    Vector3 vertex3;
    int depth;
    float material1; // float for first material value amount (in %)  deals with blending
    float material2; // float for second material value amount (in %)  deals with blending

    Vector3 vValue;  // place holder for vertex properties "set"
    int dValue;  // place holder for depth properties "set"

    public TriXYZ(Vector3 pos1, Vector3 pos2, Vector3 pos3, int tDepth)
    {
        vertex1 = pos1;
        vertex2 = pos2;
        vertex3 = pos3;
        depth = tDepth;
    }

    public TriXYZ(Vector3 pos1, Vector3 pos2, Vector3 pos3, int tDepth, float tMaterial1, float tMaterial2)
    {
        vertex1 = pos1;
        vertex2 = pos2;
        vertex3 = pos3;
        depth = tDepth;
        material1 = tMaterial1;
        material2 = tMaterial2;
    }

    // public access to triangle data, read-write

    public Vector3 GetVertex1
    {
        get { return vertex1; }
        set { vertex1 = vValue; }
    }
    public Vector3 GetVertex2
    {
        get { return vertex2; }
        set { vertex2 = vValue; }
    }
    public Vector3 GetVertex3
    {
        get { return vertex3; }
        set { vertex3 = vValue; }
    }
    public int GetDepth
    {
        get { return depth; }
        set { depth = dValue; }
    }



    public Vector3 Midpoint(Vector3 pos1, Vector3 pos2, int tDepth)
    {
        Vector3 midpoint;  // returned midpoint between the two inputted vectors

        //PLACEHOLDER

        return midpoint;
    }

}
}
```

and ICOSAHDRON:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;

namespace Icosahedron_Test
{
class Icosahedron
{
    int radius;  // radius of the planet
    int refinement;  // number of times to refine the traingles
    int faces = 20;
    Vector3[] basePositions; // Vertex points for three defining rectangles
    TriXYZ[] vertices;  // Vertex points for triangles which define the spherical surface

    public Icosahedron(int tRadius, int tRefinement, TriXYZ[] tVertices)
    {
        radius = tRadius;
        refinement = tRefinement;
        vertices = tVertices;
    }

    protected void Initialize()
    {
        double t = radius*((1+Math.Sqrt(5))/2);

        Vector3[] basePositions = 
        {
            //First Rectangle
            Vector3.Normalize(new Vector3(-radius, (float)t, 0)),
            Vector3.Normalize(new Vector3(radius, (float)t, 0)),
            Vector3.Normalize(new Vector3(-radius, (float)-t, 0)),
            Vector3.Normalize(new Vector3(radius, (float)-t, 0)),

            //Seconds Rectangle
            Vector3.Normalize(new Vector3(0, -radius, (float)t)),
            Vector3.Normalize(new Vector3(0, radius, (float)t)),
            Vector3.Normalize(new Vector3(0, -radius, (float)-t)),
            Vector3.Normalize(new Vector3(0, radius, (float)-t)),

            //Third Rectangle
            Vector3.Normalize(new Vector3((float)t, 0, -radius)),
            Vector3.Normalize(new Vector3((float)t, 0, radius)),
            Vector3.Normalize(new Vector3((float)-t, 0, -radius)),
            Vector3.Normalize(new Vector3((float)-t, 0, radius))
        };

        TriXYZ[] vertices =
        {
            new TriXYZ(basePositions[0], basePositions[11], basePositions[5], 1),
            new TriXYZ(basePositions[0], basePositions[5], basePositions[1], 1),
            new TriXYZ(basePositions[0], basePositions[1], basePositions[7], 1),
            new TriXYZ(basePositions[0], basePositions[7], basePositions[10], 1),
            new TriXYZ(basePositions[0], basePositions[10], basePositions[11], 1),

            new TriXYZ(basePositions[1], basePositions[5], basePositions[9], 1),
            new TriXYZ(basePositions[5], basePositions[11], basePositions[4], 1),
            new TriXYZ(basePositions[11], basePositions[10], basePositions[2], 1),
            new TriXYZ(basePositions[10], basePositions[7], basePositions[6], 1),
            new TriXYZ(basePositions[7], basePositions[1], basePositions[8], 1),

            new TriXYZ(basePositions[3], basePositions[9], basePositions[4], 1),
            new TriXYZ(basePositions[3], basePositions[4], basePositions[2], 1),
            new TriXYZ(basePositions[3], basePositions[2], basePositions[6], 1),
            new TriXYZ(basePositions[3], basePositions[6], basePositions[8], 1),
            new TriXYZ(basePositions[3], basePositions[8], basePositions[9], 1),

            new TriXYZ(basePositions[4], basePositions[9], basePositions[5], 1),
            new TriXYZ(basePositions[2], basePositions[4], basePositions[11], 1),
            new TriXYZ(basePositions[6], basePositions[2], basePositions[10], 1),
            new TriXYZ(basePositions[8], basePositions[6], basePositions[7], 1),
            new TriXYZ(basePositions[9], basePositions[8], basePositions[1], 1),

        };
    }

    private TriXYZ[] Refinement(TriXYZ[] rVertices, int rRefinement)
    {
        TriXYZ[] tVertices;  // Temp list of triangles

        int cDepth = 1; // current depth integer

        TriXYZ vertex1; // position of first vertex of base triangle
        TriXYZ vertex2; // position of second vertex of base triangle
        TriXYZ vertex3; // position of third vertex of base triangle
        int tDepth; // depth of the current triangle

        TriXYZ mid1; // position of first midpoint
        TriXYZ mid2; // position of second midpoint
        TriXYZ mid3; // position of third midpoint

        int listPos = 0; // base list position integer
        int nListPos = 0; // new list position integer

        int cRefine = 1; // current refinement iteration

        while(cRefine < rRefinement)  // loop until the icosphere has been refined the inputted number of times
        {
            tVertices = null;

            foreach (TriXYZ i in rVertices)
            {
                TriXYZ cTriangle = tVertices[listPos];

                vertex1 = cTriangle.GetVertex1;
                vertex2 = cTriangle.GetVertex2;
                vertex3 = cTriangle.GetVertex3;
                tDepth = tVertices[listPos].GetDepth;

                mid1 = TriXYZ.Midpoint(vertex1, vertex2, tDepth);
                mid2 = TriXYZ.Midpoint(vertex1, vertex2, tDepth);
                mid3 = TriXYZ.Midpoint(vertex1, vertex2, tDepth);
            }
        }

        return rVertices;
    }

}
}
```

Comment: where is the property for `GetVertex1`

Comment: I'm not following you, isn't that: public Vector3 GetVertex1  {  get { return vertex1; }  set { vertex1 = vValue; }  }   -  It's in the post, is that not how you declare a property?

Comment: As I can see your `triangleList` is not a TriXYZ[]. Can you post more code?

Comment: Whoud sound  strange to me that GetVertex function returns Vector..that is a problem, by me.

Comment: Shouldn't it be value instead of vValue?

Comment: Can you confirm what line this error is thrown on? Without your commentary I'd have assumed it was on the line where you are assigning to cTriangle since that is the only think declared as a TriXYZ in your code so it must be there that it is trying to convert...

Comment: I added the full code at the bottom of the post.    The error is being thrown on cVertex1 = cTriangle.GetVertex1; in the Icosahedron Class   .

Comment: Make simple object of TriXYZ and check the error!

Comment: Perhaps he's debugging this in release or elsewhere with code optimization on.  I suspect that the break point doesn't match the correct code line.

Comment: That went way over my head... I understood debugging... and I know what optimization means....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declare GetVertex1 like so:

```
public Vector3 GetVertex1
```

This is fine assumign that's what you want. However in the isocahedron class in the Refinement method you have the following snippets:

```
    TriXYZ vertex1; // position of first vertex of base triangle
    TriXYZ vertex2; // position of second vertex of base triangle
    TriXYZ vertex3; // position of third vertex of base triangle
    ...
    ...
    vertex1 = cTriangle.GetVertex1;
    vertex2 = cTriangle.GetVertex2;
    vertex3 = cTriangle.GetVertex3;
```

So this is then trying to set vertex1 to be a Vector3 when it is declared as a TriXYZ.

Work out what types things should be and you should be sorted. :)

Comment: @Tocco: That's what happens when I want a 10 minute distraction from work. :)

Comment: I feel like such a moron.  Thank you... That fixed the problem.  Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

```
  TriXYZ vertex1; // position of first vertex of base triangle   
  TriXYZ vertex2; // position of second vertex of base triangle   
  TriXYZ vertex3; // position of third vertex of base triangle
```

these lines overriding Vertex3 of 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Vector3' to TriXYZ so you would change the object name of TriXYZ

Comment: someone beat you to the explanation, that was the problem.  Thank you though.